# How to change the position of pane in Tmux

Tags: tmux

I want to change the postion of a pane such as that I want to change pane 4 to pane 3 after pane 3 exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider using layouts and `rotate-window`. For example if you are using `main-vertical` layout and close the "main" window, then:

1. Reset the layout with `C-b M-4`.
2. Rotate up or down (`C-b C-o` or `C-b M-o`) until the desired window is main.

You might also want to change the prefix to a shorter version. I like back-tick, so I have this in my `tmux.conf` file:

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix `
bind-key ` send-prefix
```

And to make `C-o` and `M-o` repeatable add:

```
bind-key -r C-o rotate-window -U
bind-key -r M-o rotate-window -D
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as answer. The Q was about panes, not windows.

Comment: From the man page for `tmux` for `rotate-window`: Rotate the positions of the panes within a window, either upward (numerically lower) with -U or downward (numerically higher).  -Z keeps the window zoomed if it was zoomed.

Answer (score 61):

To change pane 4 to pane 3 after pane 3 exits:

```
C-b {          move the current pane to the previous position
```

Here are more shortcuts for moving panes around:

```
C-b }          move the current pane to the next position
C-b C-o        rotate window ‘up’ (i.e. move all panes)
C-b M-o        rotate window ‘down’
C-b !          move the current pane into a new separate
               window (‘break pane’)
C-b :move-pane -t :3.2
               split window 3's pane 2 and move the current pane there
```

Source: [tmux cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2921703)

Comment: Just for clarity, previous position is the position of the pane with lower index.